# Left bit shift operation in C

Tags: c, bit

I'm trying to shift the variable 'a' that has a value 1111 and shift it to the left so I could get 1110 meaning it should print the number 14. However, it is printing 30. I'm thinking that because it is shifting but it doesn't take the most left bit out (11110) but it should have been 1110. Here is my code. Thank you.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
unsigned a;
a=0xF;
a=a<<1; 
printf(": %u\n",a);
```

Comment: `unsigned a` != `unsigned char a`. The number is really `0x[0000]000F` (depending on whether it's a 16- or 32-bit unsigned int). Shifted: `0x[0000]001E` == 30.

Comment: @EOF eh? It would be 30 even if the shift was done in 8 bits precision

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Yes. I was pretty tired when I wrote that. I do maintain that it contains no factual errors, though it *may* be slightly misleading.

Answer (score 8):

Your `a` variable is declared as `unsigned` -- this means it is an `unsigned int`, which usually has 32 bits. So when you put `0xF` into it, it really contains `0x0000000F`, or

```
00000000000000000000000000001111
```

in binary.

When you shift that one position to the left, it contains

```
00000000000000000000000000011110
```

or 30 in decimal. (0x1e in hex)

If you want to restrict it to just 4 bits, you'll want to `AND` the result with 0xF after every shift operation, like

```
a = a << 1;
a = a & 0xF;
```

That will result in `a` containing just `1110` (but really containing `00000000000000000000000000001110`)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `unsigned` is short for `unsigned int` and on most modern systems, an `int` is defined to be 4 bytes (32 bits). In any case, it's certainly more than 4 bits.

You are right in that "it doesn't take the most left bit out".

If you want you can bitwise `&` it with `0xF` which will set any bits to the left of the last 4 bits to `0`.

```
a = (a << 1) & 0xF;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you left shift a number the left most bit is not dropped it just moves to the left. So, when you left shift 1111 you will get 11110. For convenience, you can remember that whenever you left shift a number it is multiplied by 2 and when you right shift it you are in fact dividing it by 2.The drop would occur only if the type of bits that you have assigned run out for that number. In this case you will get garbage values as an answer. So your output is correct in context with what you are doing. But if you want to get 14 from 15, I suggest you use subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

Shifting 1111 to the left would result in 11110, which is indeed 30. Try reading this really good answer to a related question, I Think you got the wrong idea of bit shifting.
[What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)